# Problem rendering template after my code has run Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Hello I have the code below in my views.py.

```
@csrf_exempt
def stk_push_callback(request):

  data = request.body
  got_data = json.loads(data)
  result_code = got_data['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode']
  result_desc = got_data['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultDesc']

  print(' ')
  print('ResultCode: ', result_code)
  print(result_desc)
  print(' ')

  room = room_val()
  check_in = in_val()
  check_out = out_val()
  user = user_val()

  if result_code == 0:
      booking = book_room(user, room, check_in, check_out)
      print (booking)
    
      return render(request, 'booking/paymentcomplete.html')

  else:
      return render(request, 'booking/paymenterror.html')
```

paymentcomplete.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> {% block title %} Hotelio|Payment Complete {% endblock title %}</title>

</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}

    <!-- Navbar is loaded from base.html here -->
    
    <h1>Payment hass been approved. Click below to view your bookings</h1>
    <div class="home">
        <a href="{% url 'booking:BookingListView' %}" class="text-decoration-none"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left">Your Bookings</i></a>
    </div>

    {% endblock content %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

paymenterror.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> {% block title %} Hotelio|Payment Error {% endblock title %}</title>

</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}

    <!-- Navbar is loaded from base.html here -->

    <h1>An error occured during payment processing</h1>
    <div class="home">
        <a href="{% url 'booking:RoomListView' %}" class="text-decoration-none"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left">Home</i></a>
    </div>

    {% endblock content %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

I believe the code is running well since `print(booking)` produces below results

[image]

paymentcomplete.html is supposed to render once the system receives a `result_code == 0`, any other result should then render the paymenterror.html. I do not receive any error they just don't appear. Please advice.

What exactly am I doing wrong because the templates don't render?

EDIT

I receive the error below which i think is related to the `got_data = json.loads(data)` line in views.py

```
JSONDecodeError at /daraja/stk-push
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "templates don't render"? What results do you get? Add a [mre] to your question. For instance you should have added the templates to the question...

Comment: Hello, @AbdulAzizBarkat I have updated the question you may have a look again. Regards.

Comment: What appears instead?

Comment: @Roy Thande please add your `base.html` template.

Comment: @tobias You make refer to latest edit

Comment: @RoyThande OK, then it's pretty clear that the view function isn't returning anything.

Comment: @tobias Why is that?

Comment: @RoyThande It stops at `json.loads` because you're not receiving valid JSON. Print `request.body` and take a look.